# Difference between Control Template and DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate

What is difference between a `ControlTemplate` and a `DataTemplate` in WPF?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Typically a control is rendered for its own sake, and doesn't reflect underlying data. For example, a `Button` wouldn't be bound to a business object - it's there purely so it can be clicked on. A `ContentControl` or `ListBox`, however, generally appear so that they can present data for the user.

A `DataTemplate`, therefore, is used to provide visual structure for underlying data, while a `ControlTemplate` has nothing to do with underlying data and simply provides visual layout for the control itself.

A `ControlTemplate` will generally only contain `TemplateBinding` expressions, binding back to the properties on the control itself, while a `DataTemplate` will contain standard Binding expressions, binding to the properties of its `DataContext` (the business/domain object or view model).

Comment: Did that make sense? I guess I'm trying to explain the philosophical differences rather than the technical ones.

Answer (score 126):

Very basically a `ControlTemplate` describes how to display a Control while a `DataTemplate` describes how to display Data.

**For example:**

A `Label` is a control and will include a `ControlTemplate` which says the `Label` should be displayed using a `Border` around some Content (a `DataTemplate` or another Control).

A `Customer` class is Data and will be displayed using a `DataTemplate` which could say to display the `Customer` type as a `StackPanel` containing two `TextBlocks` one showing the Name and the other displaying the phone number. It might be helpful to note that all classes are displayed using `DataTemplates`, you will just usually use the default template which is a `TextBlock` with the `Text` property set to the result of the Object's `ToString` method.

Comment: Voted up for the simplicity of the description. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 35):

[Troels Larsen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/troels%20larsen/?ws=usercard-mini) has a good explanation on [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ba37a337-8d62-4343-9155-0a5093467649)

> ```
> <Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
>   <Window.Resources>
>     <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonContentTemplate">
>       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>         <Grid Height="8" Width="8">
>           <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>            Margin="0,0,1.8,1.8" 
>            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" 
>            Data="M0.5,5.7 L0.5,0.5 L5.7,0.5"/>
>           <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>            Margin="2,3,0,0" 
>            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" 
>            Data="M3.2,7.5 L7.5,7.5 L7.5,3.5"/>
>           <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>            Margin="1.2,1.4,0.7,0.7" 
>            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" 
>            Data="M2.5,2.5 L7.5,7.5"/>
>           <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>            Margin="1.7,2.0,1,1" 
>            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" 
>            Data="M3,7.5 L7.5,7.5 L7.5,3.5"/>
>           <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
>            Margin="1,1,1,1" 
>            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" 
>            Data="M1.5,6.5 L1.5,1 L6.5,1.5"/>
>         </Grid>
>         <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
>       </StackPanel>
>     </DataTemplate>
>     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate">
>       <Grid>
>         <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
>         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
>               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
>       </Grid>
>     </ControlTemplate>
>   </Window.Resources>
>   <StackPanel>
>     <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" Content="1"/>
>     <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" Content="2"/>
>     <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" Content="3"/>
>   </StackPanel>
> </Window>
> ```
>
> (Templates blatently stolen from
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx
>   and
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate%28VS.95%29.aspx
>   respectively)
>
> Anyway, the ControlTemplate decides how the Button itself looks, while
>   the ContentTemplate decides how the Content of the button looks. So
>   you could bind the content to one of you data classes and have it
>   present itself however you wanted it.

Answer (score 25):

`ControlTemplate`: Represents control style.

`DataTemplate`: Represents data style(How would you like to show your data).

All controls are using default control template that you can override through template property.

**For example**
`Button` template is a control template.
`Button` content template is a data template

```
<Button   VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate >
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
                            <Button Content="Show Name" Click="OnClickShowName" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>

public String UserName
{
    get { return userName; }
    set
    {
        userName = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`ControlTemplate` - Changing the appearance of element. For example `Button` can contain image and text

`DataTemplate` - Representing the underlying data using the elements.

Answer (score 2):

`ControlTemplate` DEFINES the visual appearance, `DataTemplate` REPLACES the visual appearance of a data item.

Example: I want to show a button from rectangular to circle form => Control Template.

And if you have complex objects to the control, it just calls and shows `ToString()`, with `DataTemplate` you can get various members and display and change their values of the data object.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above answers are great but there is a key difference that was missed. That helps make better decisions about when to use what.  It is `ItemTemplate` property:

- DataTemplate is used **for elements that provide ItemTemplate property** for you to replace its items' content using `DataTemplate`s you define previously according to bound data through a selector that you provide.
- But **if your control does not provide this luxury for you** then you still can use a `ContentView` that can display its content from predefined `ControlTemplate`.  Interestingly, you can change the `ControlTemplate` property of your `ContentView` at runtime. One more thing to note that unlike controls with `ItemTemplate` property, you cannot have a `TemplateSelector` for this (ContentView) control.  However, you still can create triggers to change the `ControlTemplate` at runtime.